# android nested LinearLayout sizing

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to achieve the following layout for my expandable listview.

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8HDx.png)

**Problem:**

On android previewer the layout looks as expected:

> refer to first image in attachment below.

However, when I run it on an emulator or a device the second TextView is not displayed.

> refer to second image in attachment below

I have to set the height of the second ImageView (ivGroupIndicator) to match parent in order for the second TextView to display. But this stretches the expandable arrow icon.

> refer to last image in attachment below

[Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hi4fN.png)

Here is my layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ci_hand_cursor"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/route_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Dhelhi Belhi"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/route_schedule_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="20-September-2017"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivGroupIndicator"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/group_indicator"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: The problem maybe is that you set the height of the parent layout to 50dp. Try to it to wrap content

Comment: Could you attach the second image? It is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

- Use `0dp` as height/width when using weights
- Weight can just be 1 (not 0.8)
- Use equal weights on the 2 text views so they share equal vertical space
- Set gravity to `center_vertical` on text views so the text is centered.
- set scale type on image so it doesn't stretch.

  ```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:orientation="horizontal">

      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="25dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:scaleType="centerInside"
          android:src="@drawable/ci_hand_cursor" />

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:paddingLeft="5dp"
          android:paddingTop="5dp">

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/route_name"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:text="Dhelhi Belhi"
              android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
              android:textSize="16sp"
              android:textStyle="bold" />

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/route_schedule_date"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:text="20-September-2017"
              android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"
              android:textSize="14sp" />
      </LinearLayout>

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/ivGroupIndicator"
          android:layout_width="25dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:background="@drawable/group_indicator"
          android:scaleType="centerInside" />
  </LinearLayout>
  ```

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. This is what i am getting now: https://s24.postimg.org/i4kh1mwbp/img5.png the layout in the middle is squashed up

Comment: Just increase the top level LinearLayout's height to something higher than `50dp`.  Maybe `80dp`?

Comment: Fixed :) I changed the height of second LinearLayout to wrap_content from match_parent and that did the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem maybe is that you set the height of the parent layout to 50dp. Try to set it to wrap content, and use `height=0dp` and `weight=1` for the vertical `LinearLayout`